# SVG images / internet explorer uncompatible when using a JavaScript slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, svg

I am trying to use SVG icons and even though they work fine in Chrome, they don't in Internet Explorer.

[I've added it to codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adKobQ)

```
<svg style="" id="pdf-file" height="18" width="18" class="pdf-file">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#fa-file-pdf-o"></use>
</svg>
```

Open in Chrome and you will be able to see some small icons on the top left corner, but nothing is displayed if you open in Internet Explorer, any idea why/how to fix?

Comment: Your pen works for me in IE 11.0.9600.17239.

Comment: Which internet explorer browsers do you need to support? In which you are having issues?

Comment: I need to support  Internet Explorer 10-11, I'm having issues on Internet Explorer 11.0.10240.16431 , can you see them fine on your Internet Explorer?